# Deployment of Web API on azure devops waits because permissions needed without showing which

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, devops, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that needs to be deployed to our TEST Windows server. I have the pipeline yaml set up to do so.

All previous steps have run correctly, namely:

- Build
- Unit Tests
- Package Nuget Libraries

Deploying the Web API is next, as you can see here:

[image]

The deployment stage is on hold because it is waiting for needed permissions (no clue which).

I have an environment called `TEST`, which on devops seems to be registered technically as environment1 (see that reference on the right):

[image]

There originally was an extra check that said permissions to `TEST` are needed, but I could click PERMIT for that. Seems fine now.

**My question**

As you can see the remaining check says "permission needed", but to my knowledge it doesn't show which permissions. I see Agent there, so it could be related to the agent, but it still doesn't help me. So

1. What permission is needed?
2. If you know, what action do I need to do to grant it?

**Update**

I half suspect that if I had elevated rights I would see a PERMIT button for this as well and I could just click it away so the job would continue. Obviously alas I do not. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission pop up ***is for your Service connection or user or Agent pool from the Test environment to access the resources referenced in the YAML pipeline*** And once you click on permit the next time you run the pipeline it won't ask for the permission again as the Agent pool used to run the pipeline has been given access to run the pipeline.

Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#q-why-do-i-see-the-message-that-i-need-to-authorize-a-resource-before-the-run-can-continue) for more details on the permission required to run the pipeline and access the resources used to run and manage pipeline. *The Build Administrators and Release Administrators group will allow complete access for the management of Build and Release pipelines. You can add your service connection or user in these groups: -* [**Reference Link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#pipeline-permissions-reference) for Build pipeline permission.

***You can add the permission for your Agent pool to access all the pipelines like below: -***

***Go to Project setting > Pipelines > Agent pools > Select your Agent pool > Security > Open access > Click Open access: -***

[image]

[image]